# Adjusting the admin_level of countries in osm-bright style?

Tags: openstreetmap, style, cartocss, css

I'm using [OSM Bright style](https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright)

Unfortunately, this style favours more `admin_level=3` countries than `admin_level=2`, for instance, on the map below, Transnistria is labelled instead of Moldavia.

[image: Example]

How to change that?